# Populating a treeview using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, database, ado.net, treeview

I am very new to ADO.NET and I tried populating a treeview as shown in the figure. But I am getting errors.

This is my code:

```
private void PopulateTreeView()
{
    treePatient.Nodes.Clear();

    SqlDataAdapter daPatient = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT pId, pBillDate, pName FROM tPatients WHERE pBillDate >= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())", con);

    SqlDataAdapter daDate = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM viewGroupDate", con);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    daPatient.Fill(ds, "tPatients");
    daDate.Fill(ds, "viewGroupDate");

    // Add root node
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode("Patients");
    root.Tag = 0;
    root.Expand();

    ds.Relations.Add("Dept_SubDept", ds.Tables["viewGroupDate"].Columns["pBillDate"], ds.Tables["tPatients"].Columns["pBillDate"]);

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["viewGroupDate"].Rows)
    {
        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["pBillDate"]);

        TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", dt));
        tn.Tag = 0;

        foreach (DataRow drChild in dr.GetChildRows("Dept_SubDept"))
        {
            TreeNode childTn = new TreeNode(drChild["pId"].ToString() + "- " + drChild["pName"].ToString());
            childTn.Tag = drChild["pId"];

            tn.Nodes.Add(childTn);
        }

        root.Nodes.Add(tn);
    }

    treePatient.BeginUpdate();
    treePatient.Nodes.Add(root);  
    treePatient.EndUpdate();
}
```

Hope you guys can help me. Thanking you.

Comment: take a look to :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview?view=netframework-4.8  and https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-TreeView-server-control-in-ASPNet-with-examples-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx   and https://www.grapecity.com/blogs/getting-started-with-treeview-for-asp-net-mvc   and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.childnodes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_TreeNode_ChildNodes

Comment: Add the proper tags to get the right references. Looks a WinForms project.

Comment: you're welcome. @Hw Dulanjana

Comment: That's ADO.NET, not Entity Framework.  You'll need to post the errors too.  For `dr.GetChildRows("Dept_SubDept")` to work you need a DataRelation in your DataSet.  perhaps you should start over with Entity Framework.